# how to decompression texture in android opengl es 2.0

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures, opengl-es-2.0

I am having a ETC1 compressed texture.i am using below code to decompress and load the same,

```
 public void LoadCompressedTexture()
{
    GLES20.glGenTextures(1, bg_grid_tex_id, 0);

    InputStream input = mContext.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.compressed_tex);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,bg_grid_tex_id[0]);

    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
    try{
        ETC1Util.loadTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0,GLES20.GL_RGB, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_6_5, input);
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("DEBUG! IOException"+e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

[image: decompressed texture]

i am getting the image shape as expected but the size is small, remaining portion is filled with black.

Is there any way to set the height and width before decompressing, so that the size of decompressed image will change??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you share the original compressed PKM image file?

Firstly, is your compressor configured to round up width and height to the nearest power or two, and therefore padding the image with black? If so fix this offline (don't pad) or adjust your texture coordindates.

Secondly, if the input texture is correct then the size of the texture on screen has nothing to do with the size of the texture image; it depends on the input geometry of your triangles and the texture coordinates at each vertex. How are you drawing the quad on screen?

Comment: vertices = new float[]
                {
                        0.0f, 0f, 0.0f,
                        mScreenWidth, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                        0f, mScreenHeight, 0.0f,
                        mScreenWidth, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                        mScreenWidth,mScreenHeight,0f,
                        0f, mScreenHeight, 0.0f,
                };

        textureCords = new float[]{
                0.0f,1.0f,
                1.0f,1.0f,
                0.0f,0.0f,
                1.0f,1.0f,
                1.0f,0.0f,
                0.0f,0.0f,
        };  GL_TRIANGLES,0,6 ;

Comment: using above vertices and cords i am drawing the quad using GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES,0,6);

Comment: decompressed texture size is 1024*1024

Comment: size of bitmap used to commpress is 531*754

Comment: So based on that it looks like your compressor is rounding up to the nearest power of two and padding out the image. You just need to adjust your texture coordinates to crop off the padding; e.g. use 0.0 -> 0.518 for width, and 0.0 -> 0.736 for height.

Comment: is there any way to configure ETC1 compressor??

Comment: It's definitely possible in some compressors (although they will normally still round up to a multiple of 4, as that is the ETC block size). I have no idea what compressor you are using, so can't easily help here ...

Comment: i am using ETC1Util